# Racket : How do i print the mysql result in a HTML page

Tags: html, mysql, racket

I am trying print the values from the DB on the HTML page generated in APPLICATION.rkt

but this is what i see when i execute the code below

```
&createstring;&db-conn;SELECT * from students
```

Here is what I am trying to execute:

```
#lang racket
(require db)
(require web-server/servlet)
(provide/contract (start (request? . -> . response?)))

(define db-conn
      (virtual-connection
         (lambda () (mysql-connect   #:server "localhost"
                 #:port 8889
                 #:database "SOB"
                 #:user "root"
                 #:password "root"))))




(define (start request)
  (define (createstring id name sid)
    (string-append "id is " id "and name is " name "and sid is "  sid))
  (response/xexpr
   '(html
     (head (title "SOB"))
     (body 
      ,@(map (h1) (map createstring (in-query db-conn "SELECT * from students"))))
     )))


(require web-server/servlet-env)
(serve/servlet start
               #:launch-browser? #f
               #:quit? #f
               #:listen-ip #f
               #:port 8080
               #:extra-files-paths
               (list (build-path "/Users/lalith/Documents/LALITH FILES/MDX/SOB/" "htmlfiles"))
               #:servlet-path
               "/servlets/APPLICATION.rkt")
```

Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrnog?

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple problems.

First, use `quasiquote` (or "backquote") instead of `quote`; otherwise you can't escape from it with `,@` (ie, `unquote-splicing`). In other words, change

```
'(html ___)
```

to

```
`(html ___)
```

Then, inside the `,@` escape, your `map`s are wrong, and `map` doesn't work with `in-query` anyway. You probably want something like this instead:

```
,@(for/list ([(id name sid)
              (in-query db-conn "SELECT id, name, sid from students")])
    `(h1 ,(createstring id name sid)))
```

Or something like that. (The code above would make a level-1 header for each row in the table, if that's what you want.)

---

*Edited in response to comment:* It looks like `id` is a numeric column in the database. If you have a recent version of Racket, I recommend using `~a`, which is like `string-append` but automatically converts non-string values to strings first. Change the definition of `createstring` to this:

```
(define (createstring id name sid)
  (~a "id is " id "and name is " name "and sid is "  sid))
```

In older versions of Racket (before `~a`), use `format` instead (see the docs for how).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt and very useful reply..

the query is excuted now and getting the reply, but i get a 'contract violation' error message

Sorry am a begginner in Racket


string-append: contract violation
  expected: string?
  given: 1
  argument position: 2nd
  other arguments...:
   "id is "
   "and name is "
   "A"
   "and sid is "
   "B"